# Como fazer imagens/vídeos se auto ajustarem?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css3

Olá, estou terminando de desenvolver um app, coloquei nele as imagens com 450px de largura, pensando que funcionaria, pois atualmente todo dispositivos tem no minimo 480x800 de resolução, ao compilar fui testar no smartphone com essa resolução e a imagem fica grande, fora do limite do body.. Não sei o que está acontecendo, estou usando o código assim:

```
<div align="center"><img src="imagens/inicio.jpg" class="imagem" /></div><br>
```

A class imagem é apenas para colocar uma sombra.. Como faço para as imagens se redimensionarem de acordo com a tela do dispositivo?

Comment: Fica dentro do body sim, o que ele fica fora é do limite da tela. Você precisa aprender sobre layouts responsivos.

Comment: possível duplicata de [Design Responsivo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/58524/design-responsivo)

Comment: Sim fica dentro do body,porém não dentro do limite que estabeleci para ele, o design está responsivo, apenas enfrentei um pequeno problema com as imagens do artigo.. Usei Bootstrap para deixa-las responsíveis sem ter que ter várias imagens de tamanhos diferentes.

Comment: Entendi leandro, na verdade para funcionar nas imagens é necessário adicionar os elementos `col-*`, mas pode não funcionar corretamente, o link no meu segundo comentário pode ser o caminho.

Comment: Olha na resposta como eu fiz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom, a solução foi mais simples que pensei, com o uso do bootstrap consegui fazer, para isso, coloque a imagem assim:

```
<img src="..." class="img-responsive" alt="...">
```

E no `head` da página coloque esta folha de estilo do bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: Boa resposta Leonardo +1, retirei o voto de fechamento

Comment: Bootstrap é a solução mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Uma abordagem diferente da apresentada e sem o uso da `Twitter-Bootstrap` seria o uso das tags  do HTML5.

Veja o exemplo abaixo (exeute-o em um arquivo html para ver corretamento o resultado o no jsfiddle se tiver um monitor razoavelmente grande):

```
<picture>
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 650px)"
    srcset="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/2010ChevroletCamaro-05.jpg">
  <source 
    media="(min-width: 465px)"
    srcset="http://s2.glbimg.com/TysmL9iPCRj8F5opJUW-p-_AfsY=/620x349/s.glbimg.com/jo/g1/f/original/2013/04/05/camaro-hotwheels01.jpg">
  <img 
    src="http://gruposaodomingos.com.br/site/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Foto-de-Camaro.jpg" 
    alt="a cute kitten">
</picture>
```

Aqui definimos uma imagem padrão e outras imagens de dimensões menores para serem trocadas quando o browser tiver seu tamanho reduzido a um valor (determinado).

Fonte mais detalhada: [Link](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/responsive/picture-element/?redirect_from_locale=pt)

**Obs:** Nunca usei `class="img-responsive"` porem minhas imagens sempre ficaram resposivas, julgo que pelo fato delas estarem envelopadas dentro de uma `row`, `container` e `wrapper`.

Comment: Poderia me falar o poque do `downvote`?

Comment: É Ricardo, tem sempre alguem que não entende o objetivo real da comunidade infelizmente, pega um +1 para compensar.